# How to Share Files with apps in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, file, share

I'm new to Android programming, and I'm trying to share files with apps, because I've already tried:

```
final Uri arquivo = Uri.fromFile(new File(absoluteFileName));
        final Intent _intent = new Intent();
        try {
            _intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arquivo);
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Venho informar a perda de um material com o seguinte anexo: ");
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Meu pdf");
            _intent.setType("application/pdf");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(_intent, "Compartilhar"));
        }catch (Exception error){
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Ocorreu um erro ao criar o seu relatório", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

and the following error occurs: E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0

And how do I share files on Android's top API 29?

Comment: "and the following error occurs: E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0" -- that seems to be unrelated to your app. `Uri.fromFile()` has been obsolete since Android 7.0. Use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to get a `Uri` for use with `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: already tried however the error persists.

Comment: Again, that error message seems to be unrelated to your app. If you believe that your app is crashing, you should find a stack trace in Logcat.